# How to prove these linear congruence equations?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am answering a exercise consisting of three parts.

Here are the exercises:

Suppose $p$ is an odd prime.

1) Show that if $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $p$ doesn't divide $a$ then there exists unique $a'$ (unique here means unique modulo $p$) such that $aa' \equiv 1 \mod p$.

2) Find the values of $a$ for which $a \equiv a' \mod p$.

3) Show $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \mod p$.

I have done 1) by saying since $p$ doesn't divide $a$ then the only common factor must be $1$ since $p$ is prime so the $\text{hcf}$ is $1$ and so there is only one (that is unique) solution to the equation $ax \equiv 1 \mod p$ call this solution $a'$ and we are done.

For 2) and 3) I am utterly lost.

Could anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem say "$p$ doesn't divide $a$", but your solution to 1) says "$a$ doesn't divide $p$". Since $p$ is prime most values of $a$ won't divide $p$, but $a=1$ will divide $p$.

Comment: Perhaps you mean to be asking about $\Bbb Z_p$ instead of $\Bbb Z$.  What *will* be true is that given $a\in \Bbb Z_p$ with $a\neq 0$ there is a unique $a'\in \Bbb Z_p$ such that $aa'\equiv 1\pmod{p}$... I.e. you are being asked to show that multiplicative inverses are unique in the ring $(\Bbb Z_p,+,\times)$

Comment: Yes I mean that they are unique modulo $p$. And my answer contained a typo which has since been fixed. Any help on parts 2/3?

Comment: For 1) prove existence via euclidean division algorithm and that $p$ is coprime to $a$.  For uniqueness, suppose you have $aa'\equiv ab' \equiv 1\pmod{p}$ with $a'\not\equiv b'\pmod{p}$ and left-multiply by $a'$, giving $a'\equiv b'\pmod{p}$ a contradiction.  For 2) notice how $1^2=1$ and $(-1)^2=1$.  Are there any others?  For 3), use what you learned in 2)

Comment: I get 1) but I don't understand what you are hinting at in 2) sorry.

Comment: Do you get why $1\cdot 1\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ and why $(-1)\cdot (-1)\equiv 1\pmod{p}$?  (*rewriting the second one as $(p-1)\cdot (p-1)\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ if it still isn't obvious*).  Now, we know of at least two values of $a$ such that $a\equiv a'\pmod{p}$.  There still remains the question of whether there are any others.  For this, use some group theory... are you aware of the fact that $\Bbb Z_p^*$ is cyclic?  What does that imply about the number of elements of order two?  If you don't know about cyclic groups, then how about the roots of the polynomial $X^2-1$ in $\Bbb Z_p[X]$?

Comment: For 3) recognize that every term in the product can be paired with its multiplicative inverse with the exception of those numbers such that $a\equiv a^{-1}\pmod{p}$.,  So, you have for example in $\Bbb Z_7$ the product $(7-1)!=1\cdot \color{red}{2}\cdot \color{blue}{3}\cdot \color{red}{4}\cdot \color{blue}{5}\cdot 6$, the red numbers pair together and cancel eachother, the blue numbers cancel eachother, the black $1$ does nothing, and the black $(6)$ can be thought of as $7-1$ instead

Comment: Nevermind I still don't get it thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

For 2), $a\equiv a' \mod p$ means $a^2=1$. Now the congruence classes $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$ are a field, which implies the quadatic equation $a^2-1=0$ has at most two roots. And indeed it has: $1$ and $-1$ˆ.

For $3)$ (which is known as *Wilson's theorem*), note that each congruence class $a$, except the classes of $1$ and $p-1\equiv 1$, which are their own inverse, is associated with *another* class $a'$  such that $aa'\equiv 1$. So
$$(p-1)!= 1\cdot2\cdots\cdot (p-2)(p-1)\equiv 1\cdot(-1)\cdot\!\prod_{2\le a\le p-2}\!a\equiv 1\cdot(-1) \cdot1^{\tfrac{p-3}2}=-1. $$